# Google Sheets Hyperlink to Dynamic Field Within a Given Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets document with a series of fields for every day in the year. The top row (Actually, row 2) is the Months (by full name, eg. January, February, etc.). The A column is numeric, from 1 to 31. There are several fields for each date, so the fields in the A column are merged (in other words, it's not A2, A3, A4 - more like, A2, A7, A12).

What I'd like to do is put a a hyperlink at, say, B1, that points to "today's" top field. So, today's would point to J7, and I could just click the link at B1, and get taken directly to that field.

I know this is going to involve the HYPERLINK function, but I can't figure out how to get it to work. Something like:

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=0&#range=" & MATCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM"),2:2,0) & MATCH(DAY(TODAY()),A:A,1),"Click for today")
```

But I can't get it to work right. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your months are in every column from B2:M2:

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=*000000000*&range="&ADDRESS(MATCH(DAY(TODAY()),A2:A,1)+1,MONTH(TODAY())+1,4),"Click for today")
```

I wrote the formula so that the link could go in A1 without running into trouble, if you like. (It would also work in B1, etc.)

If there are spaces between your months, just reorder what you had so the MATCH for the row is first and wrap it in ADDRESS( *row*, *column*, 4):

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=*000000000*&range="&ADDRESS(MATCH(DAY(TODAY()),A2:A,1)+1,MATCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM"),2:2,0),4),"Click for today")
```

(To be clear for future users, you'd need to replace the gid= number with the actual number corresponding to your sheet.)

Comment: Close. But it got me where I needed to be, so thank you so much. I was missing two key funtions: ADDRESS, and SUBSTITUTE. Here's what wound up working. (Note: In my case, the gid **is** 0.)

Comment: The ADDRESS function the way I proposed it was specifically ADDRESS(row, column, 4). The last argument of 4 is what sets ADDRESS not to have the $ markers.

Comment: I see. I _knew_ it could be done without the SUBSTITUTE. But somehow, when I tried it, it didn't work for me. I must have done it wrong. Thanks for the solution, in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Tyler - Close. But it got me where I needed to be, so thank you so much. I was missing two key funtions: ADDRESS, and SUBSTITUTE. Here's what wound up working. (Note: In my case, the gid **is** 0.)

=HYPERLINK("#gid=0&#range="&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(MATCH(DAY(TODAY()),A:A,1),MATCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM"),1:1,0)),"$",""),"Click here")

The ADDRESS line the way you proposed it results in the address in the format $A$1, which the HYPERLINK function doesn't like. Using that just brought be to the sheet, but not the actual cell. By using SUBSTITUTE to get rid of the $ marks, that resolved the problem.)

Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like I could have done it with just ADDRESS too, but in the meantime, this is working.

Comment: The ADDRESS function the way I proposed it was specifically ADDRESS(row, column, 4). The last argument of 4 is what sets ADDRESS not to have the $ markers.

Comment: Btw, I adjusted it. Took out the SUBSTITUTE function, and fixed the 4 for relative value. It works perfectly, and is a simpler function. So thanks again!